# Variable no of argument in C Macro

Tags: c, unix, macros, embedded, c99

I am writing some hardware specific code, where I want to use C Macros, the macro definition would be something like this:-

```
#define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE,RESOURCE1) if(a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != x1) || \
                                                               (a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != y1)) \
                                                         a[MODE][RESOURCE1]=x3;
```

Since sometimes I can have more then 1 resource to allocate, such as:-

> ```
> #define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE_1(MODE,RESOURCE1,RESOURCE2) if(a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != x1) || \
>                                                                (a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != y1)) \
>                                                                          a[MODE][RESOURCE1]=x3;
>                                                         if(a[MODE][RESOURCE2] != x1) || \
>                                                                (a[MODE][RESOURCE2] != y1)) \
>                                                          a[MODE][RESOURCE2]=x3;
> ```

Is there any way I can write a macro, which covers both cases, as it takes variable number of arguments?

I have used variable number of arguments, in macro for printf macros, but then how I will address those arguments, by their respective name, for example, if I modify the MACRO definition such as:0-

```
#define VALIDA_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE,.....)
```

How will I identify RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2?

Comment: You "can" but don't. What you have now works. I would redefine the second in therms of the first: `#define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE_1(MODE, RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2) VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, RESOURCE1); VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, RESOURCE2)` and then I would wrap _both_ of them in `do { ... } while(0)` so that they behave as proper statements. (Also, never your macro with a semicolon.)

Comment: But in that case, if suppose first macro fails, I want to do exit, Which is not possible until unless I check its return value...

Comment: As currently written, neither of those macros has any return value.

Comment: Yes... I am sorry for not being very clear.. yes, but it should return back with an Error code, in case of resource being used,.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite it to return said code. I recommend using the ternary conditional `?:` instead of `if`, and then a comma operator to perform the assignment and return the value (the code `x = y, z` will assign the value of `y` to `x`, but return the value of `z`). Then, for the double version, you can combine these return values with a boolean operator (if you desire short-circuit behavior and the return values are pass/fail) or a bitwise operator (for no short-circuit or more complex return values). As it stands, I don't know what you would realistically return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macros have a lot of repeated code in them.  Simplifying them helps make a solution more apparent:

```
#define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE_1(MODE,RESOURCE1,RESOURCE2) do {\
    VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, RESOURCE1); \
    VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, RESOURCE2); \
} while(0)
```

Here, it's clearer that this is simply a repeated invocation of the first macro while iterating through a list of arguments.

Assuming you know that the data types being used here will always be consistent, you can try something like this (untested and written off of the top of my head):

```
#ifdef HARDWARE_PLATFORM_A
  static sometype args[] = {
      RESOURCE1,
      RESOURCE2,
      /* ... etc, etc */
  };
#elif defined HARDWARE_PLATFORM_B
  static sometype args[] = {
      RESOURCE10,
      RESOURCE11,
      /* ... etc, etc */
  };
/* repeat for all hardware platforms */
#endif

void initialization_function (void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(args) / sizeof(args[0])); ++i) {
        VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, args[i]);
    }
}
```

where `sometype` is the data type of the arguments that you will be using for `RESOURCE1`, `RESOURCE2`, etc.

Given the complexity of what you are trying to do, you'd be a lot better off writing a function to do the iteration instead of a macro.  You can still use a macro to create the `RESOURCE` list, but don't try to get the pre-processor to do the iteration for you.  If you need to avoid the overhead of a function call (since you tagged this as 'embedded'), you can declare the functions `inline` and the result should be as efficient as using a macro.  In the process, though, you'll gain things like type safety.

While it might be technically *possible* to do this with a macro, it would be a nasty hack that would most likely bring more problems than benefits.  Doing complex procedural tasks with the pre-processor rarely turns out well.

The other alternative that you have is to use a code generator that takes a list of `RESOURCE` arguments from a file and generates a .c file containing the initialization code.  The code generator would be written in a language much more powerful than the C pre-processor (almost any scripting language could be used here).  This probably wouldn't be worth the trouble unless you had a long list of `RESOURCE`s, though.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish it is don't pass in a variable number of arguments, but stick with two and make the second one be a list that can be used in an initialization.  For example (trailing backslashes left off for clarity):

```
#define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, LIST)
{
    int resources[] = LIST;
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < sizeof(resources)/sizeof(int); count++) {
        /* do stuff here for each resources[count] */
    }
}
```

And then you can simply call it as such:

```
VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE, { RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2 } )
```

Note: there is more than one way to skin this cat, so pick your favorite answer and go with it :-)

Comment: That's not "assignment", that's "initialization." Note that intialization allows for `{ RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2 }` to be used, which I suspect is what you intended: mere assignment would not allow this.

Comment: This won't work, as the preprocessor will treat `{ RESOURCE1` and `RESOURCE2 }` as two arguments rather than a single argument containing a comma.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - Oh dang, I forgot about that. I think enclosing it in parentheses would still work, though. (As a hack, you could make `LIST` into `__VA_LIST__` and hope people do it right, but that seems undesirable.)

Comment: Yep, you're right of course.  You actually can pass things in ()s though.  But that won't help since the initialization won't take the ()s that are passed in with them.  Otherwise `(1, ({2,3}))` would work.  But then you end up having to create a function that takes the second argument and returning a static array pointer or something and then it starts feeling **really** hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be too silly? ;-)

```
#define VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(MODE,RESOURCE1,RESOURCE2)                \
if(a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != x1) || (a[MODE][RESOURCE1] != y1))                     \
a[MODE][RESOURCE1]=x3;                                      \
if((RESOURCE1 != RESOURCE2) && (a[MODE][RESOURCE2] != x1) || (a[MODE][RESOURCE2] != y1)))   \
a[MODE][RESOURCE2]=x3;
```

and Call it as below for single resource

```
VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(M1,R1,R1)
```

and like below for two?

```
VALIDATE_RESOURCE_AND_ALLOCATE(M1,R1,R2)
```